# Determine whether T is a matrix transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have these question

Determine whether T is a matrix transformation

A) $T(x,y,z)= (0,0)$

B) $T(x,y,z)=(1,-1)$

C) $T(x,y)= (xy,y)$

In the book A is matrix transformation but not B ? Why? And what about C? Please help

Comment: Do you know the definition of a matrix transformation (what is more often called a linear transformation)? If so, it's an easy application of that definition to test each of the above maps.

Comment: As it is put, this doesn't make sense. You need quantification on $(x,y,z)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linear transformation must send $\vec 0$ to $\vec 0$ and it should satisfy $T(cx+y)=cT(x)+T(y)$

**$A)$** is trivial transformation sends everything to $0$ which is ok.

**$B)$** It does not send to $0$ to $0$.

**$C)$** You can see that it does not satisfies the $T(cx+y)=cT(x)+T(y)$.

Comment: Dose it mean that the only number that T can transform it is 0?

Comment: no,The ones that goes to $0$ named as $ker(T)$ and $ker(T)=\{0\}$ if and only if $T$ is one to one.

Comment: As an example let $T(x,y)=(x+y,0)$ it has infinitly many zeros.